# What free Kanban boards link with TFS

Tags: tfs2010, planning, kanban

I am working in a small agile team and would like a free online Kanban board that links with TFS. The reason that I would like it to link to TFS is to cut the admin of entering in all the stories and having to update another piece of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at this project on Codeplex for a WIP board that you could use in as a Kanban board.  It appears to be process agnostic.  It does not appear to have moved out of Beta 2 so I am not sure what the level of stability is or if it is getting any work done on it any longer.  It does integrate with TFS 2010 though.

Visual WIP
http://visualwip.codeplex.com/

The author is Hakan Forss and at least one blog post about the project is here:
http://hakanforss.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/first-prototype-of-team-foundation-server-2010-kanban-board/

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at TFS 2012.  It now has a Kanban board in the tool.  There is a [preview version of the TFS service in the cloud](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) available if you want to check it out.

When I looked into it for TFS 2010, I was only able to find free Kanban tools that did not link to TFS, or paid ones like [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com/) that could actually integrate with TFS 2010.

Comment: Thanks my work only have licence for 2010 I have seen that the 2012 version has the kanban. My work unfortunately are not willing to pay either.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps no link with TFS, but consider to use [Trello](https://trello.com/): it's free and worth it!

Comment: Thanks but there is no burn down chart available on Trello

Answer (score 1):

We used to use [TFS Workbench](http://tfsworkbench.codeplex.com/) before we upgraded to TFS 2012. Its a Windows based application but used to work well.

Comment: The [TFS Workbench](https://tfsworkbench.codeplex.com/) has now been upgraded to support TFS 2012 and MS Scrum 2.2.